# Mozilla firefox button after enable/disable always mouseovered

Tags: jquery, html, css, button, mozilla

I have a problem with a standard button in Mozilla Firefox (other browsers works well).
After enable/disable button becomes always blue (mouseovered).

button script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".crbutton").click(function(){
        $(this).prop("disabled",true);
        setTimeout(function(){$(".crbutton").prop("disabled",false);}, 710);
    });
});
```

css button:

```
.crbutton{
    position: fixed;
    width: 5%;
    height: 5%;
    right: 0%;
    top: 47.5%;
}
```

How to can I fix this problem?

Comment: I'm assuming you mean it has the "active" button style?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems fairly straightforward. When you do this,

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".crbutton").click(function(){
        $(this).prop("disabled",true);
        setTimeout(function(){$(".crbutton").prop("disabled",false);}, 710);
    });
});
```

you're simply toggling the disabled state. The button still has focus, though, which is why you're seeing the "active" or "focused" state when it's re-enabled, as seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/d8yqbcq2/.

To remove focus, simply add a call to `.blur()`, like so: http://jsfiddle.net/d8yqbcq2/2/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".crbutton").click(function () {

        $(this).prop("disabled", true);
        setTimeout(function () {
            $(".crbutton").prop("disabled", false);
        }, 710);

        $(this).blur(); // added this
    });
});
```

Comment: Thx it helps! But why button still focused after enable/disable only in mozilla??

Comment: @user3931692 No idea. I don't know of any spec that says what the browser is expected to do with focus when the element is disabled.